# Using Amazon Web Service with Paperclip and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm developing a photo sharing application with rails. Since the application will be focused on photo sharing, image upload time is important. From two points, a user shouldn't wait more than 3-4 seconds for an image upload and when hundreds of people are sharing photos at the same time, that shouldn't matter also.

A guy is talking about some good information for me [here](http://aaronvb.com/articles/paperclip-amazon-s3-background-upload-using-starling-and-workling.html).

For my situtation, if I basically use paperclip gem with AWS, that means every image will be queued and if many people are posting images, they would be wait for minutes... Also I have to take care about heroku timeout...

So is this true that AWS or Paperclip is not suitable for me, or what should I do to handle this?

Comment: Why do you say that people's images will be queued?

Comment: You can read the reason from the text I linked. I didn't understand properly but that guy is talking about an issue with paperclip or aws... @Max Williams

Answer (score 0):

You can have your client upload directly to S3. so basically, this how its going to work.

1. You are going to generate a pre-signed s3 URL in rails.
2. you are going to pass on this pre-signed s3 URL in upload form.
3. Enable CORS support on S3 bucket
4. Use a JS plugin like [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload file/video/photo to that that s3 pre-signed URL.

This has been detailed here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

Please read the above 2-3times, if required. It should solve your issue.